# Selecting different numbers of columns from multiple table

Tags: sql, database

I have 5 tables (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5). All these tables have different numbers of columns. Now I need to select 3 columns from T1 and if primary key from T1 exits in T2 as foreign key, then select all the columns from T1 else don't. Further if it exists in T3 then select all columns from T3 and goes all the way to T5.

Given this scenario, how do I merge all the information? Which SQL command is suitable for this kind of situation? Please help, I'm a total noob in SQL.

Comment: this is such a weird scenario that I don't think we can give you an answer without some tables structures, sample data and desired result

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: Please, confirm or correct "... primary key from **T1** *exits* in T2 ... *select* all the columns from **T1**": do you have to select columns from **T1**, not **T2**?

Comment: This is very UNCLEAR

Comment: "then select all the columns from T1" - do you mean "then select all the columns from **T2**"?